# Printing to a label printer via Python but nothing is happening

Tags: python, winapi, printing, pywin32

Driving myself crazy, desperate need of a Python pro.  I have been trying to figure this out for days on days -- at first I wasn't able to figure out setting up the connection. That error is gone now thankfully, but now my code is simply not doing anything.  There is no error, but it's also not printing the tab like I need.

My goal is to print the tab "Label" that is on my Google Sheet x amount of times. X is defined by F2 on the sheet.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import win32api
import win32print
import tkinter as tk

# Authenticate and open the Google Sheet
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', [
                                                         'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open_by_key(
    '1eRO-30eIZamB5sjBp-Mz2QMKCfGxV037MQO8nS7G7AI').worksheet('Label')


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Porter\'s Label Printer')
        self.master.geometry('400x300')  # Set the window size
        self.counter = 0
        self.total_labels = int(sheet.acell('F2').value)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.update_counter()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.print_button = tk.Button(self.master, text='Print Labels', command=self.print_labels, font=(
            'Arial', 24), bg='lightblue', padx=40, pady=40)
        self.print_button.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.counter_label = tk.Label(self.master, text='0 of {} labels printed'.format(
            self.total_labels), font=('Arial', 18))
        self.counter_label.pack(pady=20)

        self.refresh_button = tk.Button(self.master, text='Refresh', command=self.refresh_labels, font=(
            'Arial', 14), bg='lightgrey', padx=20, pady=10)
        self.refresh_button.pack(pady=20)

    def print_labels(self):
        printer_name = 'Test Printer'
        print_data = sheet.get_all_values()
        for i in range(int(sheet.acell('F2').value)):
            print_data_str = '\n'.join(['\t'.join(row) for row in print_data])
            printer_handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)
            job_info = ("Label", None, "RAW")
            win32print.StartDocPrinter(printer_handle, 1, job_info)
            win32print.WritePrinter(printer_handle, print_data_str.encode())
            win32print.EndDocPrinter(printer_handle)
            win32print.ClosePrinter(printer_handle)
            self.counter += 1
            self.update_counter()

    def refresh_labels(self):
        try:
            self.total_labels = int(sheet.acell('F2').value)
            self.counter = 0
            self.update_counter()
            self.print_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
            self.counter_label.config(fg='black')
        except ValueError:
            print('Error: could not convert F2 value to an integer')
            self.total_labels = 0
            self.counter_label.config(
                text='Invalid number of labels!', fg='red')
            self.print_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

    def update_counter(self):
        if self.counter == self.total_labels:
            self.counter_label.config(
                text='All documents printed!', fg='green')
            self.print_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        else:
            self.counter_label.config(text='{} of {} labels printed'.format(
                self.counter, self.total_labels))


# Authenticate and open the Google Sheet
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', [
                                                         'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open_by_key(
    '1eRO-30eIZamB5sjBp-Mz2QMKCfGxV037MQO8nS7G7AI').worksheet('Label')

# Create a GUI window
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(master=root)

# Run the GUI
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'd suggest to split your problem into (unrelated) pieces. There's the sheet handling, the printing. and the *GUI* stuff. Get them both working separately, and only then combine them. That way you could have a *MCVE* of a few lines of code ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) which is much easier to debug, follow and reproduce.

Comment: Great - much appreciated, will do this